# How to slow down timer in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, timer

I am making a HTML tester. I added the following code to timer.

```
Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
sb.AppendLine(RichTextBox1.Text)
IO.File.WriteAllText("htmltester.html", sb.ToString())
WebBrowser1.Navigate("file:///" & IO.Path.GetFullPath(".\htmltester.html"))
```

But it reloads very fast and makes annoying sound. Is there any way to slow down the timer to execute this command after 5 seconds ?
Thanks !

Comment: what about `SlowTimer.Interval = 5000`

Comment: Ok...i will try it...Thanks for the help ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer the [timer Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Timer's tick is controlled by setting the interval property.so make its interval to `5000` if you want to repeated it in every 5 seconds. since the interval is measured in Milli seconds.
you can set the interval by using the following code,

Let's assume that the name of the timer is `SlowTimer`:

```
SlowTimer.Interval = 5000
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not have any timing functions in it or any loops so it should just run once.

If this is just some hacky throw away code then try a `Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)` before the navigate.